# Problems with binary search algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

Binary search algorithm can't analyse data correctly, for example in the following codes written in eclipse can't give me the correct output for some specific input. The fault result occurs when i want to find the last element from an array.

For example I have an array of 5 element `{10,20,30,40,1}`
If I want to check whether 1 is in the array or not, then the below code can't give me the correct result? The following two code can't work properly, please  explain

```
import java.util.Arrays;
    public class demo2 {

    public static void main(String sabuj[]){
    int[] character = {10,20,30,40,1};
    System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(character, 1));
    }       
}
```

The above and the below code correctly analyze the data when my array elements are `{10,20,30,40,50`} and I want to search for `50` as for example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class demo {
    public static void main(String sabuj[]) {
        int c, first, last, middle, n, search, array[];

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number of elemnts: ");
        n = in.nextInt();

        array = new int[n];

        System.out.println("Enter " + n + " Elements");

        for (c = 0; c < n; c++) {
            array[c] = in.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Enter a value to Find from the Elements ");
        search = in.nextInt();

        first = 0;
        last = n - 1;
        middle = (first + last) / 2;

        while (first <= last) {
            if (array[middle] < search)
                first = middle + 1;

            else if (array[middle] == search) {
                System.out.println(search + " found at location "
                        + (middle + 1) + ".");
                break;

            } else
                last = middle - 1;
            middle = (first + last) / 2;
        }
        // if (first > last)

        System.out.println(search + " is not present in the list ");

    }
}
```

Comment: Binary search alghoritm is defined for SORTED array. There is no way to use it on not sorted one.

Comment: From the documentation of `Arrays.binarySearch`: "The array must be sorted" - is {10,20,30,40,1} sorted?

Comment: at least read the doc for the methods you are using. It is the minimum you can do.

Answer (score 5):

Clear case of RTFM ;-)

From the documentation:

> The array must be sorted

So please just do that before searching ;-)

Comment: and for anyone who doesnt know what RTFM is, then Read The Fin Manual

Answer (score 3):

Binary search requires that the data is sorted. This is why it doesn't work on input such as

```
{10,20,30,40,1}
```

The reason is that binary search will start looking in the middle. If the sought element is smaller than the middle element, it will continue the search in the left half. When the algorithm can't find the value in the left half, it will assume that the value is not present in the array.

Comment: thanks a lot sir, i got it :) which algorithm is best to work with the unsorted data?

Comment: A plain linear search: `for (int i : arr) { if (i == whatYoureLookingFor) return true; } return false;`.